# R - fortify forecast object transformation generating wrong dates

Tags: r, dataset, data-science

I am trying to plot a forecast object by transforming it into a fortify object, as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177663/how-to-plot-a-subset-of-forecast-in-r) stack overflow topic.

Here is the link to the [dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Xy0X0JPjEvmFtTJzd01kCQWl7Imu5ezM), and below you will find the code that generate the two objects (emea and df1) which should have the same date as one is tranformation based on the other.

```
# Load required libraries
library(forecast)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(ggfortify)

# Load dataset
emea <- read.csv(file="C:/Users/nsoria/Downloads/AMS Globales/EMEA_Depuy_Finanzas.csv", header=TRUE, sep=';', dec=",")

# Create time series object
ts_fin <- ts(emea$Value, frequency = 26, start = c(2014,11))

# Pull out the seasonal, trend, and irregular components from the time series 
model <- stl(ts_fin, s.window = "periodic")

# Predict the next 3 bi weeks of tickets
pred <- forecast(model, h = 5)

# Round values to better accuracy
pred$mean <- round(pred$mean)

# Convert pred from list to data frame object
df1 <- fortify(pred) %>% as_tibble()

# Convert ts decimal time to Date class
df1$Date <- as.Date(date_decimal(df1$Index), "%Y-%m-%d")

# Remove Index column and rename other columns
# Select only data pts after 2017
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  select(-Index) %>% 
  filter(Date >= as.Date("2017-01-01")) %>% 
  rename("Low95" = "Lo 95",
         "Low80" = "Lo 80",
         "High95" = "Hi 95",
         "High80" = "Hi 80",
         "Forecast" = "Point Forecast")
```

Here is an screenshot of the [first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5vgl.jpg) object (emea) and the [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/om0pa.jpg) object (df1).

My first assumption is that has something to do with the time zone as I am getting below error:

```
Warning message:
In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz = tz) : unknown timezone '%Y-%m-%d'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Adding what worked for me, suggested in another post.

```
ts_fin <- ts(emea$Value, deltat = 1/24, start = c(2014, 21))
```

This help me to get an accurate time series.